# Probability of event given PMF

Tags: probability

Given a pmf $$p(k) = (1 - \beta)\beta^k$$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$, 
$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{outcome is even number}\right) = ?$ 
The event space (the power set of positive integers) is countably infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may say that
\begin{align*}
P(\text{outcome is even}) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(2k) \\
&= (1-\beta) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \beta^{2k}.
\end{align*}
This sum is a geometric series, and so we get 
$$
P(\text{outcome is even}) = (1-\beta) \frac{\beta^{2}}{1-\beta^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. A follow up to this:
What would the probability be that that outcome takes a value x given that the outcome is greater than y.
I believe this conditional probability. So it will be probability of intersection divided by probability that outcome is greater than y. Is this correct? How do I go about finding the probability that outcomes is greater than y? @Jesse

Comment: @user100503 You're welcome! Conditional probability sounds like the way to go for your new event, and you can compute the probability that the outcome exceeds y by summing p(k) from y+1 to infinity. You'll still have a geometric series.